How to interpolate a type name as a string literal inside an invocation of the quote macro (from the quote crate)?
I'm trying to write a proc_macro that automatically implement a trait for a struct. The trait is as follows
trait StructName {
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

However, I found it hard to escape quote mark in the quote macro, for example, the following code is not working
let self_ty: Box<syn::Type> = ...;
quote!(
    impl StructName for #self_ty {
        fn name(&self) -> &'static str {
            \"#self_ty\"
        }
    }
)

How to escape quote mark in the quote macro?

did you mean stringify!(#self_ty)?

Right, I don't know there's such a macro

Strings will be encoded as string literals when quote!'d. The quote crate has a ToTokens trait that is helpful for encoding AST types into their tokens which can then be converted to a string the same way that stringify! would be.
use quote::{quote, ToTokens};

let self_ty: Box<syn::Type> = ...;
let self_ty_str = self_ty.to_token_stream().to_string();
quote!(
    impl StructName for #self_ty {
        fn name(&self) -> &'static str {
            #self_ty_str
        }
    }
)

The syn crate does require the "printing" feature flag for this to work, but that is enabled by default so it shouldn't be a problem.
